# Access Internal resource in vaadin with new browser window

Tags: vaadin

I'm working with vaadin, I want to generate a report when user click the button,My report is within the application,I want to open the report within new browser window. When I try to do that, it opens the window but shows the same window I'm currently in. I used "open()" method to open new window and to for the report path I used "ExternalResource". Here is my code

```
    mainWindow.getWindow().open(
                    new ExternalResource("http://localhost:8080/myapp/reports/report.rptdesigng"),
                    "_blank", // window name
                    500, // width
                    200, // weight
                    Window.BORDER_NONE // decorations
                    );
```

Comment: See [*Handling Browser Windows*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-windows.html) in the Vaadin 8 manual. Might be of interest on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

There are different types of resources in Vaadin. Take a look at [chapter about available Resource types in the Book of Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.resources.html).

If you use the ExternalResource it only forwards the window to that URL. And unless you have registered an [URIHandler](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.resources.html) in your window, it only shows the main window instead.

So basically you have two options:

1. Register an URIHandler to your window return the report data
2. Use some other type of Resource to provide the report data

Of course there is also possibility to open another Vaadin managed window (i.e. composed of Vaadin components). You can find information and code samples about windows [in the Sampler](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#Windows).